# How can I launch a non-elevated program with an elevated AutoHotkey? (Without Task Scheduler)

Tags: windows, autohotkey

How can I launch a non-elevated program from an elevated AutoHotkey instance without using the [Windows Task Scheduler](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#BKMK_run)?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to accomplish this would be to use the [RunAs](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/RunAs.htm) command. The down-side of this is that one would have to store one's local password within the code.

`RunAs, [Username], [password here]
Run, "C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe"
RunAs ;Resets the Run command back to normal`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shell to run an application for you

[The function below is made by Lexikos](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/72812-run-as-standard-limited-user/page-2#entry522235)

> This is an ingenius method posted by blogger
>   [BrandonLive](http://brandonlive.com/2008/04/27/getting-the-shell-to-run-an-application-for-you-part-2-how/).
>   Because `ComObjCreate("Shell.Application")` creates an in-process
>   object, it can't be used directly. Instead, you retrieve the [shell
>   object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774094) of the process which hosts the desktop.
>
> The method probably requires Explorer as the shell - support for
>   custom shells is was not essential for Lexikos usage. The program is
>   always executed in the context of the process which hosts the desktop;
>   i.e. the logged on user.
>
> ```
> /*
>   ShellRun by Lexikos
>     requires: AutoHotkey_L
>     license: http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/
>
>   Credit for explaining this method goes to BrandonLive:
>   http://brandonlive.com/2008/04/27/getting-the-shell-to-run-an-application-for-you-part-2-how/
>
>   Shell.ShellExecute(File [, Arguments, Directory, Operation, Show])
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537745
> */
> ShellRun(prms*)
> {
>     shellWindows := ComObjCreate("{9BA05972-F6A8-11CF-A442-00A0C90A8F39}")
>
>     desktop := shellWindows.Item(ComObj(19, 8)) ; VT_UI4, SCW_DESKTOP                
>
>     ; Retrieve top-level browser object.
>     if ptlb := ComObjQuery(desktop
>         , "{4C96BE40-915C-11CF-99D3-00AA004AE837}"  ; SID_STopLevelBrowser
>         , "{000214E2-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}") ; IID_IShellBrowser
>     {
>         ; IShellBrowser.QueryActiveShellView -> IShellView
>         if DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(ptlb+0)+15*A_PtrSize), "ptr", ptlb, "ptr*", psv:=0) = 0
>         {
>             ; Define IID_IDispatch.
>             VarSetCapacity(IID_IDispatch, 16)
>             NumPut(0x46000000000000C0, NumPut(0x20400, IID_IDispatch, "int64"), "int64")
>
>             ; IShellView.GetItemObject -> IDispatch (object which implements IShellFolderViewDual)
>             DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(psv+0)+15*A_PtrSize), "ptr", psv
>                 , "uint", 0, "ptr", &IID_IDispatch, "ptr*", pdisp:=0)
>
>             ; Get Shell object.
>             shell := ComObj(9,pdisp,1).Application
>
>             ; IShellDispatch2.ShellExecute
>             shell.ShellExecute(prms*)
>
>             ObjRelease(psv)
>         }
>         ObjRelease(ptlb)
>     }
> }
> ```

More ways can be found in [this topic](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/72812-run-as-standard-limited-user)

Comment: Interesting. Are you sure that works for you? I just tried it and everything I ran with it seemed to be elevated. But I wasn't exactly sure how to check if a program runs elevated or not. Do you know a good way? (I run Windows with a single Admin account and UAC disabled completely btw.)

Comment: If you're logged in with an Admin account than the desktop process may also be elevated... this just uses the same process as the desktop to run a program but if that is elevated you need to use some other method.

Comment: This doesn't seem very portable.. and kind of painful to look at.

Comment: Hmm what's not portable about it? . . . Painful is in the eye of the beholder that's for sure, I think it looks like a great piece of Ahk code.

Comment: Would Microsoft's DropMyRights be a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

Run, [psexec.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) -l -d program.exe